# First time fetching API call is really slow - Node JS, React, Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, performance, express

I have a website that is making a GET call to my backend database. The first time the website calls the API it takes 11 seconds, clearly, this is too long. But if I refresh the page and give it another go, it is super fast in less than a second.

I tried to find some solutions, so I opened DevTools and found this:

[image]

For some reason, the TTFB (Time to First Byte) takes 10 seconds!

How can I reduce the TTFB the first time the website calls the Rest API?

Here is my React code which is using Axios to fetch the rest API:

```
 axios
    .get(
      "https://MY.API",
      {
        headers,
      }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        response: response.data,
      });
    })

    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
```

Here is my backend code using Express, Mongoose, and MongoDB

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await Model.find();
    res.json(response);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});
```

I would say that this is a pretty standard piece of code. I don't know why the TTFB is so much.

What tips I can implement to reduce the original wait time? This is annoying to my users.

Thanks!

Comment: You should measure on the server where the time is being spent.  Just log out times at each part of your request handler and see where the time is going.  Is it all in the `await Model.find()` or is the request not getting routed to you for awhile?  What type of hosting configuration is your server?  You have to gather this type of information yourself to know where to look for the culprit.

Comment: Alright. Thank you. I will try it!

Comment: Where exactly is the backend running? For example on Heroku free dynos there are delays when a sleeping dyno needs to be woken up.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes. I am using Heroku, and I'm on a free dyno. How would I completely remove the sleeping time? Do I need to purchase a dyno? I've seen online that if you send requests to it frequently you can stop it from sleeping?

Comment: Well, there you go then. If you want a better service than the free tier, *pay for it*. Hobby dynos aren't put to sleep, for example.

Comment: Alright. Thanks.